# Define customized type for a nested structure which all have value and label properties

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am using typescript for our project, and I need to come up with a type for the following structure which can have any number of keys,  inside each key , value and label are fixed for all option and they can be any string type value.

```
const MY_OPTIONS = {
  "keep same": {
    value: "keep",
    label: "Option 1 label text"
  },
  "select new": {
    value: "new",
    label: "Option 2 label text"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like :

```
interface MY_OPTIONS{
  [key:string]: {
    value: string,
    label: string
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
type Option = {
  value: string,
  label: string
}
type Options = Record<string, Option>;
```